# EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/home/runners/.m2/settings.xml': Github Actions

Tags: github, build, github-actions

I am creating a github actions workflow which builds the project and generates test reports. Below code is simple to understand. I am facing the below error.

Github Error that I am facing:

```
Overwriting existing file /home/runners/.m2/settings.xml
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/home/runners/.m2/settings.xml'
```

Below is the workflow code I am using.

```
name: Java Gradle Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - githubActions

jobs:
  build:
    name: Run build with Gradle
    runs-on: eg-default
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
      - name: Setup Java SDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
      - name: Run unit and integration tests
        run: ./gradlew clean test

      - name: Publish Test Report
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always() # always run even if the previous step fails
        with:
          name: Test Reports
          path: build/test-results
```

Comment: If that workflow "code" is supposed to be a YAML document, it is invalid. You cannot indent a follow up line less than the indent of the key `name`. Adding the tag [tag:yaml] to the question is inappropriate whether that is supposed to a YAML document or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible solutions to the error you’re encountering while running your pipeline:

Change the permissions of the /home/runners/.m2/settings.xml file using the `chmod` command to allow the user running the pipeline to overwrite the file.

For example, you can use the command `chmod u+w` /home/runners/.m2/settings.xml to give the owner of the file write permissions.

I hope these solutions help resolve the issue you’re facing.

Comment: It seems that the GitHub Actions environment restricts changing the permissions of certain files, including /home/runners/.m2/settings.xml.

This is my company's GitHub action environment.